# ember-qunit: You can only unload a record which is not inFlight

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

I have some unit tests that access the store. I would have thought this would be fine, so long as I wrapped them in a run callback. Unfortunately, that's not the case. I'm getting this error:

afterEach failed on #foo: Assertion Failed: You can only unload a record which is not inFlight.

As I understand it, this is exactly what [run](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html) should be preventing. My test looks something like this:

```
test('#foo', function(assert) {
  var store = this.store();
  var model = this.subject();

  Ember.run(function() {
    var secondModel = store.createRecord('secondModel', { foo: 'bar' });
    model.set('secondModel', secondModel);
    var foo = model.get('secondModelFoo');

    assert.equal(foo, 'bar');
  });
});
```

Comment: You seem to be using obsolete versions of Ember Data.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: which ember-data version you use? I'm experiencing the same problem during integration tests under beta15

Comment: Yep, I was on beta15. From what I recall, this was because I had setup my models to persist any property changes immediately, rather than waiting until `save` was called, similar to [this](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/an-autosave-pattern-for-ember-and-ember-data). I forget how I resolved the issue, though.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this is no longer an issue in Ember Data v1.13.8 in combination with Ember v1.13.7.

For following setup:

## models/first-model.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  secondModel: DS.belongsTo('second-model')
});
```

## models/second-model.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.attr('string')
});
```

## tests/unit/models/first-model-test.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { moduleForModel, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForModel('first-model', 'Unit | Model | first model', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: ['model:second-model']
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var model = this.subject();
  // var store = this.store();
  assert.ok(!!model);
});

test('#foo', function(assert) {
  var store = this.store();
  var model = this.subject();

  Ember.run(function() {
    assert.expect(1);

    var secondModel = store.createRecord('second-model', { foo: 'bar' });
    model.set('secondModel', secondModel);
    var foo = model.get('secondModel.foo');

    assert.equal(foo, 'bar');
  });
});
```

Tests pass. [Demo project repository on GitHub.](https://github.com/Kuzirashi/so-qunit-demo)